# Define one function for multiple events

Tags: javascript, function

I originally defined the same function three times for three input fields like this:

```
var inputQ = document.getElementById("quantity");
var inputC = document.getElementById("compid");
var inputR = document.getElementById("quantreq");

inputQ.onkeypress = function() {
    //code
}
inputC.onkeypress = function() {
    //same code
}
inputR.onkeypress = function() {
    //same code
}
```

But figured out it still works if shortened to:

```
inputQ.onkeypress = inputC.onkeypress = inputR.onkeypress = function() {
    //code
}
```

Will this produce any unexpected effects? And is there perchance an even shorter way of doing it, something like `('#inputQ, #inputC, #inputR) = function() {}`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work just fine (a function is just an object like any other, so you can chain assignations).

If you want a shorter way, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$("#quantity, #compid, #quantireq").on("keypress", function() {
    // code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted it to be more generic and not specify IDs everytime and without jquery you could assign each thing you need to validate/check with a class then just do something like...

```
<input id="quantity" type="text" val="0" class="check" />
<input id="compid" type="text" val="1" class="check" />
<input id="reqid" type="text" val="2" class="check" />

<script>
    function notify(){
        alert( "Here" );
    }

    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( ".check" ) ).forEach( function(){ 
        this.addEventListener( 'keypress' , notify, false); 
    });
</script>
```

This is for browsers that support forEach and querySelectorAll of course.

Comment: Thanks! Combining yours and Lucas's answer I get: `$(".classname").on("keypress", function() { });`, where the desired tags have `class="classname"`